# Force SSL using ssl_requirement in Rails 2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Rails application which need to run under SSL. I tried ssl_requirement but seems I have to type in all the actions in every controllers.

Is there any method that I can add a before_filter in application controller with ssl_requirement, so that the apps will redirect to https automatically when user request is in http?

Thanks all. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Title Changed. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use a [Rack Middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).

```
# lib/force_ssl.rb
class ForceSSL
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTPS'] == 'on' || env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
      @app.call(env)
    else
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      [301, { "Location" => req.url.gsub(/^http:/, "https:") }, []]
    end
  end
end

# config/environment.rb
config.middleware.use "ForceSSL"
```

Comment: `lib/force_ssl.rb` won't be included by default in Rails 3.0.X. You'll need to add this line to your `application.rb`: `require File.expand_path('../../lib/force_ssl.rb', __FILE__)` or do some sort of similar `require` elsewhere. Also, the `config.middleware.use "ForceSSL"` line should go in `config/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: As pointed out by Simone Carletti, in rails >= 3.1 there a force_ssl method available. See http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

Comment: Thank buddies for keep updating. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try test if request is in ssl or not in a before_filter in your application

```
class Application < AC::Base

  before_filter :need_ssl

  def need_ssl
    redirect_to "https://#{request.host}/#{request.query_string}" unless request.ssl?
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe your are not in Rails 3 ?

Comment: Should be `unless request.ssl?`?

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is that force_ssl.rb isn't being loaded and that lib isn't loaded by default in rails 3.1.  You have to add

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

to `application.rb`