# Rails 3: Make sure the user uses https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I have a Rails 3 app running on Heroku and I also have a SSL installed and working. However, my users can still access the site without the https. How do I make sure that all urls are accessed using https?

Thanks

Edit:

I've tried adding this to application_controller.rb

```
 before_filter :redirect_to_ssl

  def redirect_to_ssl
      redirect_to url_for params.merge({:protocol => 'https://'})
  end
```

But I receive a `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL using ssl_requirement in Rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861772/force-ssl-using-ssl-requirement-in-rails-app)

Comment: You should check before calling redirect. This is clearly a infinite redirect as you are redirecting always. in filter redirect_to_ssl you should first check if its not https. right?. Above content have a cleaner solution.

Comment: When I try to use ForceSSL solution, it crashes the app on Heroku.

Comment: @Zimbabao's comment is correct. You're ALWAYS redirecting to https, even when you're already on https!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an answer I posted to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861772/force-ssl-using-ssl-requirement-in-rails-app).

Otherwise, you can use [Rack::SSL](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl).

Comment: I tried Rack:SSL and worked. However, I want to limit the URL that is redirected. for example: I have myapp.com without certificate and myapp.heroku.com with certificate. I want to redirect to SSL only when it is myapp.heroku.com. thanks

Comment: Rack::SSL has an `:exclude` option. You'll find it reading the middleware code. It accepts a lambda and if the lambda returns true, Rack::SSL will be skipped.

Answer (score 7):

you may need to check if you are already using ssl... this works for us.

```
before_filter :redirect_to_ssl
def redirect_to_ssl
    redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless (request.ssl?)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a configuration setting you can use in config/production.rb or application.rb for your production environment.

```
# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
# config.force_ssl = true
```

This served me well on my Rails app without writing extra code.