# How can I redirect pages with forms to https://secure.example.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I'm using Heroku and Rails 3.1 with an SSL certificate for secure.example.com.

I only want pages with forms (secure.example.com/login, for example) to be behind secure.example.com. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's always the classic: https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement. You can also introduce some middleware for all requests or roll your own before filter as described here: [Force SSL using ssl_requirement in Rails 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861772/force-ssl-using-ssl-requirement-in-rails-app)