# Override Radiant CMS's routes from the extension to set protocol to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, radiant

I am using a CMS called Radiant (version 0.9.1), Rails 2.3.18 and Ruby 1.8.7. I have to make the routes in this gem use the 'https'. I need to do it in such a way that I won't edit the gem source files itself, but rather override the gem's routes in the extension. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of the server really depends on what your server stack looks like

To configure your rails application to use SSL you need to force ssl

In your config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

To test ssl locally I would suggest trying thin as a webserver (also put config.force_ssl in development.rb to test this )

Add:

```
gem 'thin'
```

To your gemfile and start a thin ssl server:

```
$ thin start --ssl -p 3000
```

## EDIT Rails 2 :

For Rails 2 this should work:

## lib/force_ssl.rb

```
class ForceSSL
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTPS'] == 'on' || env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
      @app.call(env)
    else
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      [301, { "Location" => req.url.gsub(/^http:/, "https:") }, []]
    end
  end
end
```

## config/production.rb

```
config.middleware.use "ForceSSL"
```

## config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../../lib/force_ssl.rb', __FILE__)
```

source: [Force SSL using ssl_requirement in Rails 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861772/force-ssl-using-ssl-requirement-in-rails-2-app?rq=1)

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I put config.middleware.use "ForceSSL" in enviroment.rb coz that's where I put the middlewares. And since I don't have application.rb in config/, I put the require in the environment.rb as well. In starting the thin ssl server, what worked for me was using "script/server thin start". But It gives "Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails." And in the browser, I got SSL Connection Error. "thin start --ssl" alone did not work, it's giving me "server: invalid option: --ssl"