# Alternative for ssl_requirement plugin for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used ssl_requirement plugin for previous versions of Rails and it is awesome. But for Rails 3 I want to try out some new plugins or gems. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

This should answer your question:

[Rails 3 SSL Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation)

Answer (score 6):

FYI there is a rails3 version of ssl_requirement, see:

https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement

The gem is call bartt-ssl_requirement

so in your Gemfile you'll want

gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'

Comment: This should be discouraged and @gjb's answer should be marked as correct

Comment: As an interim measure on the way from 2.3 to 3.1+ it's probably acceptable to use this gem, especially for the where one wants to force SSL based on some application logic (like a boolean from the database). I don't see @gjb's link would solve this problem as easily as ssl_requirement.