# Rails 3 SSL routing redirects from https to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This question relates to this [SO question and answer (rails-3-ssl-deprecation
)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation)  where its suggested to handle ssl in rails 3 using routes.rb and routes like:

```
resources :sessions, :constraints => { :protocol => "https" }

# Redirect /foos and anything starting with /foos/ to https.
match "foos(/*path)", :to => redirect { |_, request|  "https://" + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath }
```

**My problem is that links use relative paths(i think thats the correct term) and once I'm on a https page all the other links to other pages on the site then use https.**

1) Whats the best way to get back to http for pages where https isn't required? Do I have to setup redirects for all them(I hope note) or is there a better way. Would the redirects be like this:

```
match "foos(/*path)", :to => redirect { |_, request|  "http://" + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath }
```

2) If redirects back to http are required, how do I handle a case where I want all methods to be http except one? ie foos(/*path) would be for all foos methods. But say I wanted foos/upload_foos to use ssl. I know how to require it

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => "https" } do
  match 'upload_foos' => 'foos#upload_foos', :via => :post, :as => :upload_foos 
end
```

but if I put in the http redirect to the foos path what happens to https upload_foos?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want all your links to be able to switch between http and https, you have to stop using the `_path` helper and switch to `_url` helpers.

After that, using a scope with the protocol parameter forced and protocol constraint makes the urls automatically switch.

**routes.rb**

```
scope :protocol => 'https://', :constraints => { :protocol => 'https://' } do
  resources :sessions
end

resources :gizmos
```

And now in your views:

```
<%= sessions_url # => https://..../sessions %>
<%= gizmos_url   # => http://..../gizmos %>
```

---

#### Edit

This doesn't fix urls that go back to http when you are in https. To fix that you need to override `url_for`.

In any helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def url_for(options = nil)
    if Hash === options
      options[:protocol] ||= 'http'
    end
    super(options)
  end
end
```

This will set the protocol to 'http' unless it was explicitly set (in routes or when calling the helper).

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. For me its working going from http to https but not back again. Using your example: when on the http gizmos page, all links are http other than sessions which is https which is correct. If I go to the https sessions page all other links become https including the links to gizmos, even though all use the _url helper. Any ideas? I'm also not sure if I like having to use the _url helper for all links on the website when only a few require https.

Comment: Yeah, you also need to add `scope :protocol => 'http://' do end` around all your other routers. That way the helpers use http instead of https. You have to use the `_url` helpers because they generate a full url where as the `_path` helpers only generate a path.

Comment: When I do that none of the routes work other than when on the root page. root :to => "gizmos#index". If I'm on that root page all the links appear correct but on any of the other pages http or https I now get routing errors when it tries to create links with the url helper. eg. No route matches {:controller=>"gizmos", :action=>"create"}

Comment: Found a solution. Remove `scope :protocol => 'http://'` from your routes and add the helper in my edit.

Comment: That works, thanks Samuel. One last problem I have is when I go to my home page(root :to => "gizmos#index") I get redirected to a https login page, which is how I want it. After logging in I'm then taken to the root page but its https rather than http. Is there a way to write the root route that makes it http?

Comment: Easiest solution is to just use `:protocol => 'http'` with your redirect after logging in. Otherwise you will have to override the same `url_for` method in ActionController::Base like we did for your views (which is why the views urls switch back to http but urls in your controller don't).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need though the wholesale changes from `_path` to `_url` makes me nervous, there are tons of files that needed to be changed. Do I have make the same changes for `form` and `redirect` using `_path`? I don't think so since they aren't used with `url_for`. Also I would be making changes in some vendor files like devise views.

Comment: Another thought occurred to me, is it possible to override '_path' method to convert them into urls and hence achieve the same objective without the need for wholesale changes.

Comment: I wish Rails made this easier.  I'd like to not have to override url_for in the helpers and the controllers.

Comment: This is the best answer I've come across so far.  However, it kind of breaks the development environment, since there's not a certificate there; is there a way to do exactly this, but if development, not?  Or is installing a local self-signed certificate the only option?

Answer (score 0):

This was a long time ago and I'm sure it can be improved, but back on some old version of rails I had this code in application controller. Not sure this is still valid for Rails 3, but it may be of some help:

```
private
  SECURE_ACTIONS = {
    :login => ["login", "login_customer", "remind_password", "add_customer", "add_or_login_customer"], 
    :store => ["checkout", "save_order"],
    :order => ["show"] }

  # Called as a before_filter in controllers that have some https:// actions
  def require_ssl
    unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'production' or  @request.ssl?
      redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', :action => action_name
      # we don't want to continue with the action, so return false from the filter
      return false
    end
  end

def default_url_options(options)
    defaults = {}    

    if USE_EXPLICIT_HOST_IN_ALL_LINKS
      # This will OVERRIDE only_path => true, not just set the default.
      options[:only_path] = false
      # Now set the default protocol appropriately:
      if actions = SECURE_ACTIONS[ (options[:controller] || controller_name).to_sym ] and 
         actions.include? options[:action]

        defaults[:protocol] = 'https://'
        defaults[:host] = SECURE_SERVER if defined? SECURE_SERVER
      else
        defaults[:protocol] = 'http://'
        defaults[:host] = NON_SECURE_SERVER if defined? NON_SECURE_SERVER
      end
    end
    return defaults
  end
```

The `USE_EXPLICIT_HOST_IN_ALL_LINKS` was some global configuration option, but you can ignore this.

In each controller that required https, I'd add `before_filter :require_ssl` and add that controller name and its methods to `SECURE_ACTIONS`. This probably can be improved by passing the action names to the before filter, or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like how you can specify all the secure actions in one place. It makes it nice and clear whats secured. I'll be sure to give it a go in my rails 3 app if the other answer doesn't work out.