# Getting Rails URL helpers to automatically output https urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, routes

I am developing a site that mixes http and https a lot - whats the best/easiest way to make the links use the right protocol for the route - can it be specified in the routes file?

Say I have the following route in Rails 3.

```
match "/test" => "test#index", :as => :test, :constraints => { :protocol => 'https' }
```

If I'm on a http page, and I use `test_url()`, it'll output http://domain.com/test.  I want https://domain.com/test instead.

I know I can use `test_url(:secure => true)`, but that's duplicating logic.

I know I could have http://domain.com/test to https://domain.com/test, but that's an extra redirect, plus it fails on form posts.

Ideas?

Comment: I think you can find the solution from the following question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993651/

Comment: I don't know why this is so difficult in Rails. Surely most sites use HTTPS for login etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this will be solved in Rails 4! https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9b4514c3b8ecfbc40a44dbd4c2ebd4ce67f4a459

Answer (score 33):

Use `test_url(:protocol => 'https')` for https urls.

Comment: "I know I can use test_url(:secure => true), but that's duplicating logic."

Answer (score 20):

Haven't tried but add this in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
 { :secure => true }
end
```

Comment: This is a site that mixes http and https a lot though, I think that would make all the URLs https (right?)

Comment: yes, you're right, so you should only put this in the controllers having https

Comment: Still not sure how that helps me. If I'm on a http page, I want test_url() to return a https URL, not a http one.

Comment: ok, sorry about that. Remark: giving -1 to people trying to help you won't serve your cause.

Comment: Probably things changed, this no longer works in 5.1.4. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781000/474597

Answer (score 7):

```
def default_url_options(options={})
 { :protocol => "https" }
end
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 3.2 I used a combination of @apneadiving's answer. Adding the below code to my **ApplicationController**

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  options.merge{ :protocol => "https" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Rails 3 SSL routing redirects from https to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993651/rails-3-ssl-routing-redirects-from-https-to-http) answers this question pretty well.  In short, there's not a great way to do it.  I submitted the following Rails bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3571

Answer (score 0):

To generate https url, add an option called protocol with value https

```
test_url(protocol: 'https')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a plugin called ss_requirement, it will provide you with methods like
ssl_required
ssl_allowed

You can simply add this in your controller to enable ot disable https on any action

```
ssl_allowed :login, :update_profile
```

https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with generating URLs.

Comment: In this case you generate your urls as normal, but its is submitted as SSL for the methods that you have mentioned

Comment: No, it's not.  It will redirect the http post from http to https, losing the post data.