# Change protocol to https in all rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, https, routes, helper

Rails 3.1+
I want my url helpers to use the https protocol without having to specify it in every helper I call.
After searching around I've found various ways but none work, for example:

```
 ROUTES_PROTOCOL = (ENV["RAILS_ENV"] =~ /development/ ? 'http://' : 'https://')

scope :protocol => ROUTES_PROTOCOL, :path => "/app" do
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Rails 4, defining `ApplicationController#default_url_options` doesn't work. URL options are now defined in the application's routes config:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options protocol: :https
end
```

Comment: I placed the following in my production.rb  file. `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'`

Comment: Works only under console for Rails 5.1.4.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 14):

So you want it mainly for links in emails?

I think this will work in your production.rb, development.rb or any other environment.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => 'yourwebsite.com',
  :protocol => 'https'
}

# Makes it possible to use image_tag in mails
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://yourwebsite.com"
```

Answer (score 13):

In Rails 5.1.4, I have tested the following scenarios:

```
# in development.rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options({:protocol => 'https'})
config.action_controller.default_url_options(:protocol => 'https')
# Does not work

# in development.rb, outside config block
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
# Does not work, but works under console

# in routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options protocol: :https
# Does not work, but works under console

# in ApplicationController
def default_url_options(options={})
  { secure: true }
end
# Does not work

# in ApplicationController
def default_url_options
  { protocol: :https }
end
# Works in browser, but does not work under console

# in development.rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options= {:protocol => 'https'}
# Works in browser, but does not work under console
```

Comment: Did you figure it out

Answer (score 4):

For a rails 5.2.0 RESTAPI App the following worked:

In each environment file as necessary ie config/environments/test.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

Controller code:

```
 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(uploaded_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force SSL on your application, this can be done by setting `config.force_ssl` to true in your `application.rb` (or your environment specific file). More on the subject [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

**EDIT**
Ok so I don't find enough evidence for this, but I think you can override `default_url_options=(options={})` in application controller, and set `:protocol => :https` in the function body. If this does not the trick for your emails, you'll have to repeat the procedure in your environment config by adding `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`. Hope this does it!

Comment: That will cause a redirect when the request protocol is http, but I would like https in url helpers, mainly for links in emails.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code to `ApplicationController`

```
  def default_url_options(options={})
    options.merge(protocol: :https)
  end
```

You can also check out  to [Getting Rails URL helpers to automatically output https urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699881/getting-rails-url-helpers-to-automatically-output-https-urls)

Answer (score 2):

I tried all answers above, only this works for me:

config/environments/production.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

> ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux] Rails
>   3.2.22.5

Answer (score 0):

Whichever environment you want to use ssl (https://), just add this config lines to its configuration file in `config/environments`:

```
YOURAPPNAME::Application.configure do

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

Comment: That will cause a redirect when the request protocol is http, but I would like https in url helpers, mainly for links in emails.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.2.1, by default force_ssl is true, let's check

1. Open config/environments/production.rb and search "config.force_ssl"

config.force_ssl = true - no need to change

now in config/environments/development.rb - **no need to place config.force_ssl**, it should work, because your server running locally.

Ok, here is the other view

```
if !request.ssl?
  "https://" + request.host + request.request_uri
elsif request.ssl?
  "http://" + request.host + request.request_uri
end
```

Add def in helper base on above if else and in the [ActionView::Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html), 
there is a url_for method that might get you what you want if you start using that.

Comment: That will cause a redirect when the request protocol is http, but I would like https in url helpers, mainly for links in emails.

Comment: @99miles - I altered the answer, Please check, let me know if this works for you.