# Rails forms leading to Mixed Content warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, https, protocols, mixed-content

In my Rails app I use both Rails' native `form_tag` method and the `simple_form_for` method provided by the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) rubygem.

Both of them are leading to the following warning in the chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://example.com'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

And indeed, the rendered HTML forms use the `http` protocol for their `action` attribute.

What is the reason for that? All my other URL's use the `https` protocol.

Comment: Your form has http protocol specified? Usually it only has a relative path, doesn't it? How you created the form?

Comment: @EJ2015 I've used either `simple_form_for(@object)` / `form_tag(some_url)` -> no relative paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **not correct protocol** set up for your environment.

Your server is running on HTTPS and form creates HTTP URL.

You need to tell your **URL helpers** to build the URLs with the same protocol as your server is running for your environment.

**Development** should run on HTTP, **staging** should be HTTPS and **production** as well HTTPS.

There are different ways how to do it. The best is to set protocol in your environment **config file**. So place this line:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

into your environment config file like **production.rb** and **staging.rb**.

Another approach is to set the default protocol per **controller action**. [Check this one for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699881/getting-rails-url-helpers-to-automatically-output-https-urls).

In case you are using the **mailer**, also check your mailer protocol settings. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490660/1192264).