# Using rails' "post" in controller tests in rspec with scoping and protocol on routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, jruby, rspec-rails

I have a rails project that is running out of a subdirectory of the base url in production and I want it to act that way in dev so as to make dev and prod as close as possible. I have the routes file set up like so:

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
    def draw_routes
        root :to=>'foo#home'
        resources :cats, :only=>[:create] do
    end
    if Rails.env.production?
        scope :protocol=>'http://' do
            draw_routes
        end
    else
        scope :path=>"/foo", :protocol=>'http://' do
            draw_routes
        end
    end
end
```

My CatsController is like this:

```
class CatsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @cat = Cat.new(:name=>"Bob")
        if @cat.save()
            redirect_to root
        end
    end
end
```

I want to test my Create Cat Method, so I set up an rspec test in spec/controllers/cats_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe CatsController do
    describe "calling create cat with good data" do
        it "should add a cat" do
            expect {post(:action=>:create)}.to change(Cat, :count).by(1)
        end
    end 
end
```

When I run my test, though, I get

```
Failure/Error: post :create
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"cats", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/cats_controller_spec.rb:5:in `(root)'
```

Rake routes says my route is there! What is going on under the hood here, and why is this failing?

```
Rake Routes:
    cats POST   /foo/cats(.:format)            cats#create {:protocol=>"http://"}
```

Comment: try `post '/foo/cats'` instead

Comment: No dice: post 'foo/cats' yields  ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"cats", :action=>"foo/cats"} Thanks, though!

Comment: If you go for `http://localhost:3000/foo/cats`, get up to the expected place?

Comment: If I go there in the browser, yes. Also, if I have a form that posts the request, and I call it like <%=form_tag("/foo/cats",:method=>post)%>, it also goes to the right place.

Comment: Hmmm. If I remove the :protocol it starts working so it has to do with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `:protocol` is a bit wonky.

The better way to fix this, I think, is to set the protocol in your scopes to `http` instead of `http://`. If you did need to test your controller with some funky protocol, though, you should be able to do:

```
post(:action => :create, :protocol => 'funky')
```

or whatever your protocol might be.

Comment: I have to add the caveat that yes, the correct protocol is 'http' without the slashes. However, I still had to explicitly specify it in the post function. Works now, though!

Answer (score 0):

For rspec 3, this below works for me.

```
post :action, protocol: 'https://'
```