# RSpec tests failing for Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test the behavior of my ApplicationController, yet I keep running into an error. Below are my specs:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  #Base class should be inferred  
  controller do
    def not_found
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

  # Routing
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def with_error_routing
    with_routing do |map|
      map.draw do
        get '/not_found' => "anonymous#not_found",     :as => :not_found
        get '/home'      => "anonymous#home",          :as => :home
      end
      yield
    end
  end

  describe "handling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" do
    it "renders the 404 template", :failing => true do
      with_error_routing do
        @request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
        get :not_found, :format => 'html'
        response.should redirect_to(home_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error message that I keep getting is this: `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"anonymous"}`

Has anyone else faced this issue?  I feel like my examples match other examples out there of testing the ApplicationController.

Here’s the backtrace:

```
Failures:

  1) ApplicationController handling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     Failure/Error: get :not_found
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"anonymous", :action=>"not_found"}
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:544:in `raise_routing_error'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:540:in `rescue in generate'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `generate'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:573:in `generate'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:598:in `url_for'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:105:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:74:in `redirect_to'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:25:in `redirect_to'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:60:in `block in redirect_to'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:59:in `redirect_to'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/gritter-1.0.3/lib/gritter/gflash.rb:8:in `redirect_to'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb:33:in `block in force_ssl'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__1662327083837902210__process_action__2977905806469662832__callbacks'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb:17:in `process_with_new_base_test'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:475:in `process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:392:in `get'
     # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.2/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:160:in `call'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.2/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in `call'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/commands.rb:110:in `call'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:71:in `block in serve'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:66:in `fork'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:66:in `serve'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:49:in `block in run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:43:in `loop'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:43:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:37:in `start'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:95:in `block in start_child'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:82:in `fork'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:82:in `start_child'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:27:in `start'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:54:in `block in with_child'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:21:in `synchronize'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:43:in `with_child'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:62:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:47:in `serve'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:35:in `block in boot'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:35:in `loop'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:35:in `boot'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:15:in `boot'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/start.rb:13:in `call'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-0.0.8/bin/spring:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/spring:19:in `load'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/spring:19:in `<main>'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
     # /home/bryce/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.54729 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Adding ApplicationController class:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?

  respond_to :html
  respond_to :js
  respond_to :json, :xml, :except => [:edit, :update]
  respond_to :atom, :csv, :rss, :only => :index

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :respond_to_not_found
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, :with => :respond_to_access_denied

  # SECURITY - Protect Form IDs from forgery
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  protect_from_forgery

  # Helpers
  helper_method :current_user
  def current_user
    begin
      return current_customer unless current_customer.nil?
      return current_store unless current_store.nil?
    rescue
      return nil
    end
  end

  private
  def current_ability
    Ability.new(current_user)
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def respond_to_not_found
    FlashSetter.new.set(flash, nil, nil, {:flash_key => :alert, :message_key => :msg_not_found})

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_home_path }
    end
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def respond_to_access_denied
    FlashSetter.new.set(flash, nil, nil, {:flash_key => :alert, :message_key => :msg_not_authorized})

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_path }
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with_routing` block seems to work a bit differently than using normal `routes.draw` for anonymous controllers. The below will work:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def not_found
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

  it "handling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" do
    routes.draw { get "not_found" => "anonymous#not_found" }
    request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
    get :not_found
    response.should redirect_to(home_path)
  end
end
```

Edit: quotation typo, force SSL

Comment: I copied and pasted that exactly (well, I fixed the quotation mark issue in your it...end statement), but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hm, the same works for me here (after fixing the quotes), can you please post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I've added the backtrace to my original post.

Comment: Could you please post your `ApplicationController` class too?

Comment: Upon further testing, it seems to be the "force_ssl" that is causing problems.  How do I resolve that conflict?

Comment: @Bryce check this answer for using SSL in RSpec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785261/test-an-https-ssl-request-in-rspec-rails

Comment: With this method the routes need to be reloaded after the specs... It redraws all the routes...