# Force a link to bypass ssl (ruby)

Tags: ruby, http, https

I've forced the site to use https:// through .htaccess

Now I need to force these links to bypass ssl so that they load like sub.domain.com -

Right now the code looks like as follows but when I click on a link it opens with https://

```
<%  link = "" %>
<% if user.external_link.present? %>
<% link = user.external_link %>
<% else %>
<% link =  root_url(:subdomain => user.subdomain, :port => 80) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to link, :target => "_blank" do %>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993651/rails-3-ssl-routing-redirects-from-https-to-http) could help.
I'm not sure link_to's option has :protocal, although I can't find it at [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)