# How to fix wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) (ArgumentError) while upgrading Rails 4.1.5 to 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

I've undertaken upgrading my app to `rails 4.2.3` and am following the [rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-1-to-rails-4-2) for that. Everything has been going smooth so far, updated my system rubies / ruby to `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295)` and installed rails 4.2.3 successfully.

Now when I restart my app server (Unicorn), I see the following error on some of my actions:

For example, with [/login] action, sessions_controller:

```
D, [2015-07-20T15:06:47.298596 #60162] DEBUG -- : exception
D, [2015-07-20T15:06:47.303584 #60162] DEBUG -- : wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1) (ArgumentError)
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bartt-ssl_requirement-1.4.2/lib/url_for.rb:9:in `url_for_with_secure_option'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:225:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:347:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/views/widgets/sessions/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_widgets_sessions__form_html_haml__4375117426660206931_70143263158560'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/views/widgets/overlays/_signin_form.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_widgets_overlays__signin_form_html_haml__4290054271805297969_70143275176560'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/views/widgets/header/_header.html.haml:22:in `_app_views_widgets_header__header_html_haml__3443624176749641477_70143227268860'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:12:in `block in _app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__1221929868200156285_70143275930720'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:368:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:368:in `block in capture_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:608:in `with_haml_buffer'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers.rb:364:in `capture_haml'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.6/lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:61:in `capture_haml_with_haml_xss'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/helpers/conditional_html_helper.rb:12:in `cc_html'
/Users/admin/projects/MyApp/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__1221929868200156285_70143275930720'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bullet-4.14.7/lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.3.4/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.3.4/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-contrib-1.3.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.3.4/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/request_store-1.1.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/utf8-cleaner-0.0.9/lib/utf8-cleaner/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.6/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:279:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in `worker_loop'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
I, [2015-07-20T15:06:47.321716 #60162]  INFO -- :   Rendered public/500.html (0.2ms)
I, [2015-07-20T15:06:47.322306 #60162]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms (Views: 17.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2015:15:06:47 -0400] "GET /users/new HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.1464
```

I'm unable to make much of this error from the trace. It seems to come where ever there is form_helper method in the view. Something like this...

```
= form_tag login_path :id => 'new_session' do

  .field
    = text_field_tag :username_or_email, @username_or_email, class: 'input-field', placeholder: 'Username or Email', autocapitalize: 'off'
  .field.top-gap.bottom-gap
    = password_field_tag :password, nil, class: 'input-field', placeholder: "Password", autocapitalize: 'off'

  = check_box_tag :remember_me, "1", true, :id => "remember_me", :class => "hidden"

  = button_tag 'Login', :class => "medium big-blue cut-corners-small top-gap bottom-gap button", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Logging in..."}
```

Is there anyone else who has been here and fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stacktrace we can see the error is in a call to `url_for` in bartt-ssl_requirement 1.4.2. That gem was released on Mar/2012. It's not tested with rails 4.2.3 for sure (it was released even before the rails 4.0.0 release candidate).

In particular, url_for can be called with 3 arguments since rails 4.2.0. Before, it was always called with 0 or 1 arguments. [This](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2888f8653e2e0a6394e41cb4e8db2e2d81313eb7) and [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/212057b912627b9c4056f911a43c83b18ae3ab34) commit introduced the new arguments.

You could try getting rid of bartt-ssl_requirement. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110705/1389573) shows an example of how to do it.