# Rails 3 SSL Protocol links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, routes

I'm trying to create a link to a page that requires ssl, and the routes are properly set up to require it to be https, but I can't figure out how to get link_to to behave properly. I've tried writing it like this, but when I click on the link it still tries to go to an http page, not the https page like I'd expect. Am I doing something wrong?

```
link_to "Schedule a Visit!", :controller => 'visits', 
                             :action => 'new', 
                             :protocol => "https"
```

For reference, this is the appropriate part in my routes.rb:

```
scope :constraints => {:protocol => "https"} do
    resources :visits, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[Rails 3 SSL Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation)

Comment: Actually, I tried that solution and it led to infinite redirects. Not quite sure why.