# Rails + SSL: Per controller or application-wide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, router

I could use some wisdom from any developers who have worked with Rails and SSL. I have a fairly simple app and I'm in the process of implementing payment processing. Obviously payment processing calls for SSL, so I'm setting that up now.
My intention when I started working on this today was to find the simplest / cleanest way to enforce SSL on specific controller actions - namely anything having to do with payment. I figured there was no reason to run the rest of my site on SSL.

I found the [ssl_requirement gem](https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement) which seems to take care of setting SSL per-controller-action without much difficulty, so that's good. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation) which seems to indicate that handling SSL with a gem is now out-of-style.
I also found several answers / comments etc. suggesting that a site should just use Rack middleware like [Rack-SSL](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl) to force the entire site to SSL mode.

So now I'm kind of confused, and not sure what I should do. Could anyone with experience working with Rails 3 and SSL help me understand:

1. Whether I should force the whole site to SSL, or only per certain actions.
2. What *gotchas* to look out for using SSL in Rails (I've never done it before).
3. If per-controller is the way to go, whether it makes sense to use the `ssl-requirement` gem or whether I should just use the new routing and link helper options...

I'd very much appreciate your insight, this has become a paralyzing decision for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found myself "paralyzed" by this decision in the past, and here's what I think about each time.

First, keep in mind that some browsers will throw pop-up warnings if you keep switching out of and into SSL, or if you serve some content (the page) with SSL and other content (images, css) without. Obviously that's not a good experience for users.

1. The only possible downside to requiring SSL everywhere is performance. But unless you're expecting 1000+ users/day who will be doing lots of things that *don't * require SSL, this is negligible.
2. SSL is handled at the Apache/Nginx/whatever level. So if you decide to put your entire app behind SSL, it makes most sense to deal with it at the Webserver level (redirect http:/yoursite.com to https://yoursite.com.

And if, for performance reasons, you decide **not** to put everything behind SSL, then it still could make sense to handle SSL redirects at the Webserver level. Allowing your user through your Webserver, then sending him through half Rails stack, just to boot him back out to start over again is very wasteful.

Of course there's something to be said for simplicity and domains of knowledge, which would suggest handling redirects in your Rails app or middleware, since it "knows" what's safe and unsafe.

But those are things you'll have to weigh yourself. It depends on whether raw performance or simplicity of development/maintenance is more important.

I usually end up with a virtual host for http://mysite.com which redirects everything (or sometimes only certain uris) to https://mysite.com/$1. Hope that's helpful.