# redirecting from http://example.com to https://example.mysite.com

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

This question has been asked in various permutations, but I haven't found the right combination that answers my particular question.

### The configuration

- Rails 3.1 (allowing me to use `force_ssl` in my `ApplicationController`)
- Hosted on Heroku Cedar (so I can't touch the middleware)
- My SSL certs are registered for `secure.example.com`

I've already added `force_ssl` to my ApplicationController, like this:

```
# file: controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  force_ssl
end
```

### The problem

Currently, if a user navigates to `http://example.com`, force_ssl switches to SSL, but since it's NOT `secure.example.com`, it presents a warning about an unverified security cert because it's using the default Heroku cert.

(I've verified that navigating to `http://secure.example.com` properly redirects to `https://secure.example.com` and uses the proper security cert.  That's good.)

### The question

How do I force `http://www.example.com/anything` and `http://example.com/anything` to redirect to `http://secure.example.com/anything`?  (I'm assuming that force_ssl will handle the switch from http to https.)  Since I cannot touch the middleware (recall that this is Heroku hosting), I *assume* I can do something like:

```
# file: controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  force_ssl
  before_filter :force_secure_subdomain

private
  def force_secure_subdomain
    redirect_to(something...) unless request.ssl?
  end
end
```

... but I haven't sufficiently grokked redirect_to and the request object to know what to write for `something...`.  (I want to be sure that it handles query params, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can redirect to a different hostname by doing the following:

```
# file: controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl :host => "secure.example.com"
end
```

see: [rails force_ssl source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb) for more info

Comment: you may also want to provide a :protocol => 'https' argument. I saw this suggestion on related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [rack-rewrite](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-rewrite) - it's essentially Apache re-write but in Ruby form, and usable on Heroku.

This will allow you to create all sorts of Rack level rules and what redirections etc should occur and when.