# Rails 3 + HTTPS constraint in routes: The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

I am trying to force SSL only on specific URLs (user account settings in this case), and I saw this: [Rails 3 SSL Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation) . This is my original routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :thanks
    get :change_password
    get :settings
  end
end
```

I changed it to this after reading that answer;

```
resources :users do
  scope :constraints => { :protocol => 'https' } do
    collection do
      get :thanks
      get :change_password
      get :settings
    end
  end
end
```

But now lets say when I try to go on the settings page, I get an error for `The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController` when it's actually supposed to be processed by User#settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => 'https' } do
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :thanks
      get :change_password
      get :settings
    end
  end
end
```

scope first. I think...