# Rails 3: Forcing HTTP in some parts, and Forcing HTTPS in others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm currently trying to find out a way to force http for some routes (faster, no need for security) and forcing https for more sensitive pages. I saw the answer to this: [Rails 3 SSL Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634100/rails-3-ssl-deprecation) , but it doesn't seem to work.

I added a scope around my root url:

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => 'http' } do
  root :to => 'site#index'
end
```

But it just threw the error `No route matches [GET] "/"` when I tried to go to localhost:3000.

Is there a clean way to force http in some places and force https in others (I could use `force_ssl` in my controller, but is there a `force_http`?) The scope around the routes looks clean, but it isn't working for me. Am I doing it wrong?

How about a method like this?

```
CONTROLLERS_THAT_REQUIRE_SSL = ['check_out']
def ensure_proper_protocol
  unless Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    if request.protocol["https"] && !CONTROLLERS_THAT_REQUIRE_SSL.include?(params[:controller])
      redirect_to "http://" + request.host + request.path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this blog will be of any use to you:  [Always-On HTTPS With Rails Behind an ELB](http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/02/06/always-on-https-with-rails-behind-an-elb/)
 also this may also be of use to you considering you are trying to force some parts of your application to use https. [SSL Requirement](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement). It details under the section about SSL requirement adds a declarative way of specifying that certain actions should only be allow to run under SSL. Should you want to specify the entire controller in SSL then call `ssl_exceptions`

Alternatively you could try and write a `before_filter` by doing something like

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter do
    if request.ssl? || Rails.env.production? 
      redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', status => :moved_permanently
    end
   end 
 end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After looking for an answer it doesn't look like it exists, so I created a `force_http` gem... it's my first gem, and I didn't really test it out, but take a look if any of you are facing the same issues:

Install it with `gem install force_http` or you can find it here: https://github.com/EdmundMai/force_http . You just put `force_http` in the controller as you would with `force_ssl`. It's essentially just the opposite. I looked at the source code and just configured it to redirect to http:// instead of https:// when request.ssl?

Comment: How to just implement it in a specific controller method?